# Tailwind issue - some items are slightly off

Tags: tailwind-css

Not sure how to debug this, but inspecting some items that are supposedly inside a `flex`, they are still off by a few fractions of a pixel.

On the screenshot below, notice the slight variation between the `Id` / `Due Date` and the `Project` input fields. https://i.stack.imgur.com/e12g3.jpg

What could be the issue here? I tried it in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome, all facing the issue.

Edit:

Added the html snippet below

```
<div class="lg:w-4/5 mr-auto ml-auto mt-16 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
  <div class="">

    <form method="GET" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="md:flex">
        
        <div class="mx-2">
          <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold my-5" for="grid-state">
            Id
          </label>
          {% render_field invoice_filter.form.id class="w-full lg:w-40 block appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-500 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" %}
        </div>
        <div class="mx-2">
          <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold my-5" for="grid-state">
            Project
          </label>
          {% render_field invoice_filter.form.project class="w-full lg:w-40 block appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-500 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" %}
        </div>
        <div class="mx-2">
          <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold my-5" for="grid-state">
            Due Date
          </label>
          {% render_field invoice_filter.form.due_date class="w-full lg:w-40 block appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-500 text-gray-700 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" %}
        </div>
        
    
      </div>
        <button class="whitespace-no-wrap mr-5 bg-green-600 hover:bg-green-700 text-white py-2 my-2 mx-2 px-6 rounded-lg" type="submit">Apply filter</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `{% render_field ... %}` tags are just a Django specific way of adding classes to the form fields,

It essentially says

```
`<input class="...." />`
```

Comment: don't link to external sources, put your code and images into your question

Comment: also try to make sure you have a minimal reproduction

Comment: Added the source

Comment: You can make a minimal reproduction by making a code snippet from your compiled code, do not share your framework code since it has nothing to do with your issue. That said, this is an HTML5 problem, not a Tailwind issue. Consistent input sizing is not something Tailwind adds for you so you'll have to do that yourself, I usually use a height class that is slightly larger than the tallest input type when using mixed inputs like this.